# Date picker não aparece

Tags: html, bootstrap, datepicker

É o seguinte eu estou a tentar mostrar um date picker num formulario mas ele nao aparece a minha pergunta é a seguinte e possivel por o date picker num modal de bootstrap? é que eu fora do modal consigo usar o date picker dentro e que nao consigo

Deixo imagem do modal!!
[image: Imagem do Modal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom eu não sei como está o seu modal, mas você pode fazer assim.

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
      <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text"></input>
      <span class="add-on"><i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

E coloque no final da pagin, antes do fechamento da tag body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            language: 'pt-BR'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Voce testou e funcionou?

Comment: sim, veja funcionando https://codepen.io/Sinetheta/pen/Ftjwi

Comment: pois estoua  ver mas ent nao sei o que estou a fazer mal

Comment: você está usando o datepicker próprio para o bootstrap certo?

Comment: Provavelmente o problema é do meu date picker

Comment: Qual é o date picker que devo usar entao pode me indicar?

Comment: @Shider tente usar essa versão aqui: https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker